# Batchfile - The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, syntax-error

I am the owner of a Minecraft server, and am currently working on a way to make an auto-setup script so that other people can run servers more easily. I have everything finished, but upon testing it, this code is throwing a "The syntax of the command is incorrect" error. Here's the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Welcome to the startup of your new Minecraft server^^!
ECHO Upon completion of the first start, please exit the program and run "start.bat".
ECHO When you are ready, press any key.
PAUSE>NUL
SET /p "hasrun" = < "%~dp0\hasrun.txt"

:Run
IF "!hasrun!" == "0" (
    ECHO "1" >> "%~dp0\hasrun.txt"
    java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
) ELSE (
    ECHO This is not your first run^^! Use "start.bat" instead^^!
    PAUSE
)
```

The error seems to occur at the line with `ECHO "1" >> "%~dp0\hasrun.txt"`. It's been awhile since I last wrote anything in batch, so it's likely something obvious. The exact output (with echo off) is:

```
Welcome to the startup of your new Minecraft server!  
Upon completion of the first start, please exit the program and run "start.bat".

When you are ready, press any key.
```

After pressing a key to pass the `PAUSE`, it says:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
This is not your first run! Use "start.bat" instead!
Press any key to continue...
```

Also, the content of `hasrun.txt` is simply one zero. ("0" without the quotes)

Comment: I rolled back your edit. You cannot keep adding new issues to the same question once you've started receiving answers. If you now have a new issue, it's a new question and you need to post it as one. You can always provide a link to this question in the new one for reference.

Comment: Is the contents of `!hasrun!` set before this? If so, negate the `if not exist...` line from my answer, and replace `"!hasrun!"=="0 "` with `"!hasrun!"=="0"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the variable `!hasrun!`. Your method of setting the variable makes an empty or invalid variable, and if the file is empty then `!hasrun!` equals nothing, which fails the `for` loop.

---

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO Welcome to the startup of your new Minecraft server^^!
ECHO Upon completion of the first start, please exit the program and run "start.bat".
ECHO When you are ready, press any key.
PAUSE>NUL
:: Default variable set, or the for loops fails because "" does not equal "0".
if not exist "%~dp0\hasrun.txt" echo 0 >%~dp0\hasrun.txt
:: Set the file to a variable.
SET /p hasrun=<%~dp0\hasrun.txt

:Run
:: Space after "0 " appended because 0> refers to a debugging echo.
IF "!hasrun!"=="0 " (
    ECHO 1>"%~dp0\hasrun.txt"
    java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
    pause
) ELSE (
    ECHO This is not your first run^^! Use "start.bat" instead^^!
    PAUSE
)
del %~dp0\hasrun.txt
```